Doing some Encryption and Decryption and encounter "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'"
This is the view. Upon submit, the data is encrypted. No problem.:
<form asp-controller="Permit" asp-action="Encryptori" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="Roberto" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Address" name="Address" value="Viale Manfredo Fanti, 4 (50137) Firenze" class="form-control" />
</div>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="encryptAndSubmit()">Encrypt and Submit</button>
<br /><br />
@ViewBag.Display
<input type="hidden" id="Key" name="Key" value="@ViewBag.Key" />
<input type="hidden" id="IV" name="IV" value="@ViewBag.IV" />

This is the script in the View:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/crypto-js@4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script>
function encryptAndSubmit() {
    var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("Address").value;
    var key = "@ViewBag.Key";
    var iv = "@ViewBag.IV";

    var encryptedName = encrypt(name, key, iv);
    var encryptedAddress = encrypt(address, key, iv);

    document.getElementById("Name").value = encryptedName;
    document.getElementById("Address").value = encryptedAddress;
}

function encrypt(plainText, key, iv) {
    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    var ivBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, keyBytes, {
        iv: ivBytes,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return encrypted.toString();
}

And the controller.:
    private readonly byte[] _key;
    private readonly byte[] _iv;

    public PermitController()
    {
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        _key = new byte[32];
        rng.GetBytes(_key);
      
        _iv = new byte[16];
        rng.GetBytes(_iv);
    }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Encryptori()
    {
        ViewBag.Display = "";
        ViewBag.Key = Convert.ToBase64String(_key);
        ViewBag.IV = Convert.ToBase64String(_iv);
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Encryptori(IFormCollection collection)
    {
        string TheKey = collection["Key"];
        string TheIv = collection["IV"];
        var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(TheKey);
        var ivBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(TheIv);

        string encryptedName = collection["Name"];
        string encryptedAddress = collection["Address"];

        var decryptedName = Decrypt(encryptedName, TheKey, TheIv);
        var decryptedAddress = Decrypt(encryptedAddress, TheKey, TheIv);


        // Store the decrypted data in the ViewBag
        ViewBag.Display = encryptedName + "  and  " + encryptedAddress;

        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        return View();
    }

private string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string key, string iv)
{
try
{
    var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    var ivBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);

    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.IV = ivBytes;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
                cs.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            var decryptedBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
        }
    }
}
catch (CryptographicException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Decryption failed: " + ex.Message);
    return null;
}
}

I tried changing different padding mode, but still the same. Still encounter the System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. As you can see, both padding 'pkcs7' mode 'ECB' are identical in the Js and Controller.

This question is similar to: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are plenty of examples on SO or in the documentation, e.g. here, why don't you follow them? Also, ECB does not require an IV, which is why this mode is (semantically) insecure. Better switch to CBC or even better to authenticated encryption like GCM.

I resolve to using this javascript instead:
const encodedData = btoa(PlainText);

It serves the purpose. I forgot to mention that i require some encryption because the firewall blocked sending any text that contains symbols like ();!.

You should explain this in more detail! In what way should the Base64 encoding of the plaintext solve the padding problem (which it does not, see here and here). However, the answer can also be understood to mean that you have replaced encryption with encoding, which is not a real answer to the actual question and does not provide any confidentiality (since no secret/key is required for decoding).
